# Can I set a Parameter based on the output of a Stored Procedure in Informatica PowerCenter?

Tags: parameters, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica's PowerCenter, is it possible to set a parameter's value based on the output of a stored procedure?  The parameter I want to set is a parameter I defined in a flat-file data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informatica uses two kinds of objects:

- Parameters - these cannot be modified
- Variables - these can be modified during the execution of a mapping using `SETVARIABLE()` function.

You can define a variable, run stored procedure somewhere in the mapping, connect the output of `Stored Procedure` to `Expression Transformation` and add an output or variable port tu execute `SETVARIABLE($$YourVariable, sp_output)` function. At the end of a successful session, the Integration Service will save the final current value of a mapping variable to the repository.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be accomplished would be to run a script on the operating system to execute the stored procedure. The stored procedure would return the value to the script and you could insert that value into the parameter file.